# Observer Pattern Java - Multiple Observers Using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, inheritance, observer-pattern

I am trying to learn all major design patterns. I have just started to learn multithreading in java. This is observer pattern code where there are multiple observers & the observable is running in a while true loop. I'm having the following two problems:

1. When calling notifyObservers, I have to pass the new value to it even though my observers are accessing the getter of the observable value. If I don't, then the observer gets/prints value null. I have created a setter function to demonstrate it.
2. I created two observers & obviously most of the code for both of them is similar. I'm not sure how to implement new observers or create a list of observers without replicating my code. I created a basicObserver & tried to inherit it in MyObserver3, but I am not sure how exactly do I implement it.

   ```
   import java.util.Observable;
   import java.util.Observer;

   public class ObserverPatternMultipleObserversUsingThreads
   {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           ObservableValue observableObj = new ObservableValue(10);

           MyObserver1 observer1 = new MyObserver1(observableObj);
           MyObserver2 observer2 = new MyObserver2(observableObj);
           MyObserver3 observer3 = new MyObserver3(observableObj);

           observableObj.addObserver(observer1);
           observableObj.addObserver(observer2);

           observableObj.start();

           System.out.println("Calling Listeners");

           observer1.printObservablesValue();
           observer2.printObservablesValue();

           System.out.println("Main thread says: Sleeping for 3 second(s)");

           try
           {
               Thread.sleep(3000);
           }

           catch (InterruptedException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           System.out.println("Main thread says: Going to change Observables Value");

           observableObj.setValue(20);
       }
   }

   class basicObserver
   {
       private ObservableValue obsValObj = null;

       public basicObserver(ObservableValue obsVal)
       {
           this.obsValObj = obsVal;
       }

       public void printObservablesValue()
       {
           System.out.println("Observer says: [" + obsValObj.getValue() + "]");    
       }

       public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
       {
           Integer count = (Integer) arg;
           System.out.println("Observer says: Value changed to: [" + count + "]");
       }
   }

   class MyObserver3 extends basicObserver implements Observer
   {
       public MyObserver3(ObservableValue obsVal)
       {
           super(obsVal);
       }
   }

   class MyObserver1 implements Observer
   {
       private ObservableValue obsValObj = null;

       public MyObserver1(ObservableValue obsVal)
       {
           this.obsValObj = obsVal;
       }

       public void printObservablesValue()
       {
           System.out.println("MyObserver1 says: [" + obsValObj.getValue() + "]"); 
       }

       public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
       {
           Integer count = (Integer) arg;
           System.out.println("MyObserver1 says: Value changed to: [" + count + "]");
       }
   }

   class MyObserver2 implements Observer
   {
       private ObservableValue obsValObj = null;

       public MyObserver2(ObservableValue obsVal)
       {
           this.obsValObj = obsVal;
       }

       public void printObservablesValue()
       {
           System.out.println("MyObserver2 says: [" + obsValObj.getValue() + "]"); 
       }

       public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
       {
           Integer count = (Integer) arg;
           System.out.println("MyObserver2 says: Value changed to: [" + count + "]");
       }
   }

   class ObservableValue extends Observable implements Runnable
   {
       private int n = 0;

       public ObservableValue(int x)
       {
           this.n = x;
       }

       public int getValue()
       {
           return n;
       }

       public void setValue(int x)
       {
           this.n = x;
           setChanged();
           System.out.println("ObservableValue says: setChanged() has been called");

   //      notifyObservers(new Integer(this.n));
           notifyObservers();                                                                  // makes the observers print null
           System.out.println("ObservableValue says: notifyObservers() has been called");
       }

       public void start()
       {
           new Thread(this).start();
       }

       public void run()
       {
           int count = -1;
           int a=0, b=0;

           while(a==b)
           {
               if(count != n)
               {
                   count = n;
                   System.out.println("ObservableValue says: My count is: [" + count + "]");

                   count++;
                   System.out.println("ObservableValue says: Now my count is: [" + count + "]");
                   setChanged();
                   System.out.println("ObservableValue says: setChanged() has been called");

                   notifyObservers(new Integer(count));
                   System.out.println("ObservableValue says: notifyObservers() has been called");

                   System.out.println("ObservableValue says: Sleeping for 5 second(s)");

                   try
                   {
                       Thread.sleep(5000);
                   }

                   catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I would really appreciate any pointers/advice/comments regarding best practices with these concepts.

Please help.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/AsimpledemoofObservableandObserver.htm) can be useful.

Comment: Thanks @SazzadurRahaman. I understand this concept. My problem is a little specific as to why my observer is not getting the most updated value even when I am calling the setChanged() & notifyObservers() after changing the value of observable.

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't need to pass the `Observable` instance reference to the observers; that is actually a bad idea, since you get a reference to the `Observable` instance and the modified value in your `update()` method. Also, if you don't bind your observers to a particular Observable instance, you can attach them to other `Observable`s without any modification.
2. For using multiple observers, you don't necessarily need multiple classes. In your case, you can probably achieve what you want with multiple instances of the same class.

Comment: Thanks @Costi Ciudatu. I got your second point. In your first point you mentioned that the Observable instance should not be passed. You are talking about the notifyObservers method, right? That is my point exactly. I know that I should not be doing that, but if I don't, my observers ain't getting the value. Why they are not able to access the most latest value - is what I am trying to debug.

Comment: No, I was saying you shouldn't pass the observable instance as a constructor parameter to your observers. They get all the information they need in the `update()` method and it's a useless limitation to make them depend on some instance of the observable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try changing your update method to this:

   ```
   public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
   {
       if (o instanceof ObservableValue){
           ObservableValue obs = (ObservableValue) o;
           System.out.println("MyObserver1 says: Value changed to: [" + obs.getValue() + "]");
       }else{
           System.out.println("The observable object was not of the correct type");
       }

   }
   ```

This will allow you to access any methods on your observable that you need so you can get all of the values which may have changed and update accordingly.

2 I don't see much difference between your classes, can you not just create a new instance of those observers rather than having a whole class just for each one?

I have removed the classes which I don't think you need and shown how this can be done with one observer class (unless you require different functionality for each). They are numbered how they were before.

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class ObserverPatternMultipleObserversUsingThreads
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ObservableValue observableObj = new ObservableValue(10);

    MyObserver observer1 = new MyObserver(observableObj);
    MyObserver observer2 = new MyObserver(observableObj);

    observableObj.addObserver(observer1);
    observableObj.addObserver(observer2);

    observableObj.start();

    System.out.println("Calling Listeners");

    observer1.printObservablesValue();
    observer2.printObservablesValue();

    System.out.println("Main thread says: Sleeping for 3 second(s)");

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Main thread says: Going to change Observables Value");

    observableObj.setValue(20);
    }
}


class MyObserver implements Observer
{
static int numberOfObservers = 0;
private ObservableValue obsValObj = null;
private int observerNumber;

public MyObserver(ObservableValue obsVal)
{
    numberOfObservers++;
    observerNumber = numberOfObservers;
    this.obsValObj = obsVal;
}

public void printObservablesValue()
{
    System.out.println("MyObserver"+observerNumber+" says: [" + obsValObj.getValue() + "]"); 
}

public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
{


    if (o instanceof ObservableValue){
        ObservableValue obs = (ObservableValue) o;
        System.out.println("MyObserver"+observerNumber+" says: Value changed to: [" + obs.getValue() + "]");
    }else{
        System.out.println("The observable object was not of the correct type");
    }

}
}

class ObservableValue extends Observable implements Runnable
{
    private int n = 0;

    public ObservableValue(int x)
{
    this.n = x;
}

public int getValue()
{
    return n;
}

public void setValue(int x)
{
    this.n = x;
    setChanged();
    System.out.println("ObservableValue says: setChanged() has been called");

//      notifyObservers(new Integer(this.n));
    notifyObservers();                                                                      // makes the observers print null
    System.out.println("ObservableValue says: notifyObservers() has been called");
}

public void start()
{
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void run()
{
    int count = -1;
    int a=0, b=0;

    while(a==b)
    {
        if(count != n)
        {
            count = n;
            System.out.println("ObservableValue says: My count is: [" + count + "]");

            count++;
            System.out.println("ObservableValue says: Now my count is: [" + count + "]");
            setChanged();
            System.out.println("ObservableValue says: setChanged() has been called");

            notifyObservers(new Integer(count));
            System.out.println("ObservableValue says: notifyObservers() has been called");

            System.out.println("ObservableValue says: Sleeping for 5 second(s)");

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }

            catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please excuse my code formatting, I seem to be having a little fight here with the stackoverflow code view, trying to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @NutterzUK. I ran your code. The observers are not getting the updated value of the observable.

Comment: Sorry I think I am maybe confused then.. the 20? It shows for me, perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: 20 is the value which is being set for the observable. Then I increment it in the run method. It becomes 21. The observers should also follow & become 21 but they are not.